# Send Email Alert while apply Leave in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

By using the **WorkHours** in User entity ,the user will apply the leave .

[image]

To Access WorkHours in CRM : Settings -> security->Users->Open the Particular user ->In the option the workHour will display

Now I need to send email notification to the manager while the user will apply the leave in WorkHours ? how can i achieve the Task.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Work Hours is based on the `calendar` entity. You could register a plug-in on `update` message of `calendar` and detect changes to a user's calendar. In the plug-in C# code you can send the email.